# Why do my background images not align across the views?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I'm trying to do a BMW car model, but I have a problem with the blueprints in the views.

This is the problem:

[image: top view]

[image: side view]

I expected that the two images were equal, but when I fix one of the views, with the cube cover all the top blueprint, the right view blueprint has problems, because the right view is not filled by the cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your images do not show the value for the scale on both images. Make sure they are using the same value in each of the views (top, front and right).

[image]